# mapeo onetomany de la clase de recetas a la clase de ingredientes

Tags: mvc, spring, hibernate, rest, jpa

Tengo un proyecto donde estamos realizando una servicio restfull con [spring-boot](/questions/tagged/spring-boot),[jpa](/questions/tagged/jpa),[jdbc](/questions/tagged/jdbc),[spring-mvc](/questions/tagged/spring-mvc),[hibernate](/questions/tagged/hibernate)

Bueno actualmente no tengo mucha experiencia con hibernate en la relación `onetomany`.

El detalle es que por ejemplo, yo tengo una clase padre `Recetas`, en las recetas tengo una lista de ingredientes donde tengo un objeto de tipo `Recetas`.

El `onetomany` de la clase de recetas lo mapeo a la clase de ingredientes hacia el objeto de recetas el detalle es que **tengo un bucle infinito**.

Algo así:

```
RECETAS{
nombre:""
tiempo:""
etc.:""
ingredientes : [{nombre: "taltal","recetas":"{otro objeto de recetas}"}

]
}
```

Y así se sigue el ciclo infinito hacia dentro ya que cada objeto de recetas tiene un objeto de ingredientes y dentro del de ingredientes tiene un objeto de recetas .. y así seguirá.
¿Alguna idea sugerencia o recomendación? He leído por todo los lados que así se maneja pero no entiendo aun muy bien el concepto.

Comment: Te has explicado fatal, rehaz la pregunta. Si la duda es que tienes dudas en por que hibernate no entra en un bucle infinito es por las propiedades EAGER y LAZY. 

Lazy es que el metodo rellena solo los campos que vas a usar y deja los demas para inicializa despues (a lo vago) y eager lo que hace es cojerlos todos en el mismo momento. El problema es que si tienes un bucle infinito y un tipo de acceso Eager pues se va a romper hibernate y si lo tienes lazy, no rompe por que tecnicamente no los inicializa, espero que te ayude y si no echale un vistazo a esas propiedades.

Comment: No acabo de entender la pregunta: ¿Tienes un problema al servir los datos o quieres saber cómo funciona internamente?

Comment: Explica si el problema aparece al acceder a la BD (cosa del JPA) o al convertir a JSON (API REST)

Answer (score 0):

Tarde pero espero que te sirva.

Se llama bidireccionalidad y es una propiedad un tanto nueva para los que no hemos trabajado con hibernate y spring.

Te paso la respuesta traducida de [aqui:](http://%3Clink%20href=%22https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/4.1.1/yeti/bootstrap.min.css%22%20rel=%22stylesheet%22%20integrity=%22sha384-yAYSLJjzniZh9Kau9E1v1ma5CzvyHF8fPK/xUpaRx1XTH9r60WxzDivvHG3xm6Hn%22%20crossorigin=%22anonymous%22%3E)

---

La diferencia con las relaciones bidireccionales es que proveen acceso (navegación) en ambas direcciones, de manera que tu puedes accedes desde un punto u otro sin necesidad de especificar nuevas queries.

Hay que notar que el acceso de navegación no es siempre bueno, especialmente en relaciones "uno-a-muchos" y "muchos-a-muchos". Imagina un `Grupo` que contiene miles de `Usuario`;

- ¿Cómo accederías a ellos? Con esa cantidad de `Usuario` normalmente necesitarás aplicar un filtro o algún paginador, así que necesitar ejecutar un query de cualquier manera(A menos de que uses un [collection filtering](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/filters.html), que es como un hack para mi.). En algunos casos los desarrolladores tienden a aplicar el filtrado en memoria, que obviamente no es bueno para el rendimiento.  Ten en cuenta que este tipo de relación puede alentar a estos desarrolladores a usar este tipo de relaciones sin considerar el rendimiento de las mismas.
- ¿Como añadirías un nuevo `Usuario` al `Grupo`? Afortunadamente, Hibernate revisa en el otro lado de la relación cuando la persiste, asi que unicamente ocupas realizar un set a `Usuario.grupo`. Sin embargo, si tu quieres mantener objetos en memoria de manera consistente, también necesitas agregar `Usuario` a `Grupo.usuarios`. ¡Eso hará que Hibernate busque todos los elementos `Group.user` de la base de datos!

De manera que no puedo estar de acuerdo con las recomendaciones de [mejores prácticas](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/best-practices.html). Necesitas diseñar la relación bidireccional con mucho cuidado, considerando casos de uso(¿Necesitas acceder navegación en ambas direcciones? y las posibles implicaciones sobre el rendimiento.

Mirar tambien:

- [Deterring “ToMany” Relationships in JPA models](http://java.dzone.com/articles/deterring-%E2%80%9Ctomany%E2%80%9D?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:%20javalobby/frontpage%20%28Javalobby%20/%20Java%20Zone%29)

  [Hibernate mapped collections performance problems](http://Hibernate%20mapped%20collections%20performance%20problems)

  ---